# Is it okay to partition my drive while I'm downloading a huge file (4gb)

Tags: partition, download, gparted

I'm downloading a huge file using a torrent client and I was wondering if I can use GParted to partition around 100gb of my 1tb to save time because I plan to dual boot this computer right after the download finishes.

Below is my current partition.

[image]

Comment: Is the drive that you want to partition one that is in use (and mounted)?

Comment: @Sparhawk Yes it is

Comment: As Sparhawk will state, you cannot partition a drive if it is in use or mounted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the volume/partition that you wish to modify is mounted, you should not modify it. In fact, GParted [will not](http://gparted.org/faq.php#faq-9) let you modify mounted partitions:

> Why are some menu items disabled?
>
> 1. The partition is mounted and modifying a mounted partition is DANGEROUS. Just unmount the partition…

To use GParted on the boot volume, you'll need to stop/finish the torrent, then reboot from another volume. Hence, the one that you wish to modify will not be in use. The simplest way is to [download](http://gparted.org/download.php) the GParted Live image, then boot from USB or DVD.

Comment: "GParted Live is a small bootable GNU/Linux distribution for x86 based computers."

My computer is 64-bit. Will this work on mine? I'm planning to use UNetBootin to make my USB flash drive bootable...

@Sparhawk

Comment: From the download page linked in the answer: `NOTE: GParted Live is available in three different architectures… amd64: 64-bit version`. And yes, I've used it fine on my 64-bit computer via USB and UNetbootin.